# PHP obtain middle of time intervals

Tags: php, date, time

I developed a function to obtain equal time intervals within a user generated time-frame.

```
$start         = strtotime("12:00");    //start at...
$end           = strtotime("18:00");    //end at...
$timeframe     = $end - $start;         //time-frame    
$intervals     = 3;                     //number of intervals within time-frame
$interval_time = $timeframe/$intervals; //time of each interval

for($i = 0, $start; 
    $i < $intervals; 
    $i++, $start = strtotime("+$interval_time seconds", $start)) //increment time
    { 
        $new_time = date('H:i:s a', $start); 
        echo "$new_time \n"; 
    }
```

The code above outputs

```
 12:00:00 pm 14:00:00 pm 16:00:00 pm
```

What code can I incorporate to divide each interval and obtain the middle? For example to get from the code above

```
13:00:00 pm 15:00:00 pm 17:00:00 pm
```

Please kindly advise :)

Comment: Try `$start += $interval_time / 2;` on line 6. BTW is this homework? Since it seems likely to me that if you can write the code above you would be able to fix this one too...

Comment: @The Nail, thanks! The code seems to work. What do you mean by homework? I'm just new to increment operators.

Comment: @CyberJunkie what do you expect if the input is "start 12:00 end 15:00"?

Comment: @meze I get `12:30:00pm 13:30:00pm 14:30:00pm` using the new code to find median value.

Comment: @CyberJunkie I know. but is that correct?

Comment: @meze well no, the first and last interval are 30 minutes long but that's ok for the purpose of my application. What would you suggest to do when thats the case?

Comment: @CyberJunkie it depends what you need. You can replace it with `$start += ceil($interval_time / 2 / 3600) * 3600;` but check it with 13:00-14:00 pm time frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `for` loop with:

```
$half_interval = $interval_time / 2;
$mid = $start + $half_interval;
for ( $i = 1; $i < $intervals; $i ++) {
    echo date('H:i:s a', $mid) . " \n";
    $mid += $interval_time;
}
echo date('H:i:s a', $mid) . " \n";
```

Admittedly a simple approach. I'm sure improvements are possible, but leave them as an exercise for the reader!  ;-)